# How to get resque-web to work on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, resque

On my dev machine, I am able to type `resque-web` in a console and it launches a new tab on my browser which shows the Resque interface.

On Heroku, Cedar stack, how can I do the same thing?  i.e. I would like to see Resque's interface for my Heroku app.

**EDIT**

in `config/initializers/resque.rb`

```
require 'resque'
require 'resque/server'

uri = URI.parse(APP_CONFIG['redis_to_go_url'])
Resque.redis = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)

# Load all jobs at /app/jobs
Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/jobs/*.rb"].each { |file| require file }
```

in `routes.rb`

```
mount Resque::Server.new, :at => '/resque'
```

Everything works. I am now able to see the Resque web interface. However, I would like to protect this from public view. Possibly with a username and password. How can this be done?

Comment: Very helpful. [Check this out](http://railscasts.com/episodes/82-http-basic-authentication) if you just want a basic HTTP authentication.

Comment: This doc is helpful if you're using Redis To Go: https://redistogo.com/documentation/resque?language=en

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really know heroku, but if you have a **config.ru** or **Rackup** file you can run resque-web inside your own rails app, here's a sample of how to do it:

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/config/environment'
require 'resque/server'

Resque::Server.class_eval do

  use Rack::Auth::Basic do |email, password|
    user = User.authenticate( email, password )
    user && user.admin?
  end

end

app = Rack::Builder.new {
  use Rails::Rack::Static

  map "/resque" do
    run Resque::Server
  end

  map "/" do
    run ActionController::Dispatcher.new
  end
}.to_app

run app
```

**EDIT**

As you are already mounting it inside of rails, just add this statement in an initializer file:

```
Resque::Server.class_eval do

  use Rack::Auth::Basic do |email, password|
    user = User.authenticate( email, password )
    user && user.admin?
  end

end
```

Obviously, make **User.authenticate( email, password )** whatever you use to authenticate your users.

Comment: Does it matter if its `Resque::Server` or `Resque::Server.new`? I've seen examples of both!

Comment: Yes, in this example it does.

Answer (score 1):

This question and [Maurício's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7257337/1067145) are likely referring to the Sinatra app included with [Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque).

There's also [resque-web](https://github.com/resque/resque-web), a Rails Engine that can be added to an existing Rails app on Heroku. I found this to be an easier and faster solution.

Resque-web includes an interface for HTTP basic auth, which you can check out in the [project documentation](https://github.com/resque/resque-web#http-basic-authentication).